# File ‘../foo.ts’ is not under rootDir. rootDir is expected to contain all source files

Tags: serverless-framework

I have a serverless app that is composed by 3 apis. They share a large amount of code. I prepared the whole application in a way that it allows me to boot every api solely or every single one of them at the same time, regarding my needs for that moment. There are some scripts to deploy the apis separately and all in once, as well.

The problem here is the shared code. As it is shared, I needed to copy them through all apis to keep everything running smoothly, because I can't have a folder with that code outside any of the apis. It throws the error I put in the title.

My folder structure is this one:

```
src
|- api1
   |- serverless.yml (for api1)
|- api2
   |- serverless.yml (for api2)
|- api3
   |-serverless.yml (for api3)
|- common_code_1
|- common_code_2
```

I registered those 2 folders as paths in my tsconfig.json, but it throws the error anyway. How can I share this code between apis without duplicating it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using npm, I recommend creating a `package.json` file in `common_code_1` and `common_code_2`.

Then you can simply require them in the `package.json` files in `api1` with a relative path:

```
  "name": "api1",
  "dependencies": {
    "common_code_1": "file:../common_code_1",
    "common_code_2": "file:../common_code_2",
    ...
  }
```

Then, Serverless Framework will resolve those packages when packaging your application for deployment.

Comment: Although it is a good idea, it does not work. The project builds, but for every mention to those "modules", a error is thrown by typescript builder. Even though those errors were thrown, I tried to request something on the api and again, an error was thrown. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Tried it with `file:` and `file://`. Both fails exactly the same way.

Comment: I'm talking about serving the files offline, with the help of the plugin `serverless-offline`

Comment: Yup, I'm using this solution locally with serverless-offline as well, but I'm not using typescript for this project. Can you share the errors you received?

Comment: When building, for every module import, I get one of these:
`handlers/someEndpoint.ts (1,57): Cannot find module 'common_code_1'.`
When I request something, I get one of these:
`Error: Cannot find module 'common_code_1'`

Comment: Did you run `npm install` in app1 before running build?

Comment: I didn't. But all modules are installed in the root folder and it does not have any problem finding them.